# c# сообщить компилятору, что свойство не null после вызова метода

Tags: c#, .net-6

Как сообщить анализатору Visual Studio, что свойство свойства не null, после вызова внутреннего метода?

Inner class:

```
class Inner
{
    int? Property { get; set; }

    [MemberNotNull(nameof(Property))]
    void Initialize
    {
        Property = 42;
    }
}
```

Caller class:

```
class Caller
{
    // We know here that constructor is always called before other methods
    public Caller()
    {
        InnerObj = new Inner();

        // We know here that InnerObj.Property is always not null
        InnerObj.Initialize();
    }

    public Inner InnerObj { get; }

    public void MethodWithNullWarning()
    {
        // Null Warning
        InnerObj.Property.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow in Russian! As the name implies, Russian is the working language of this site. Please either translate your question into Russian or [ask the same question on StackOverflow in English](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Your question may be closed soon, but it will most likely be reopened if you choose to translate it.

Comment: Ну так у вас до сих пор свойство может быть NULL, даже если вы вызовите метод инициализации. Что мешает, к примеру сделать `InnerObj.Initialize(); InnerObj.Property = null;`? Не хотите видеть этих предупреждений, уверены, что там не может быть NULL, значит не делайте свойство `Nullable`, уберите вопросительный знак (`int?` => `int` ). Ну или задайте хотяб значение по умолчанию `int? Property { get; set; } = 0;` . Ну или глушите варнинг если уверены на 100% (`InnerObj.Property!.ToString();` (воскл. знак)).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ не все так просто, я привел лишь упрощенный случай из тонны кода для миграции на nullable типы. Дело в том, что я могу быть уверенным в том, что свойство не null, только в случае вызова метода Initialize, во внешнем конструкторе, т.е. именно у этого экземпляра Inner, который не может быть перезаписан вне конструктора (get). То есть я ищу именно способ сообщить статическому анализатору о том, что в данном случае свойство не null в любых методах этого класса, избегая ручного указания `InnerObj.Property!` (если это вообще возможно)

Comment: `<Nullable>` секцию в csproj файле удалить, тогда вообще не будет этих предупреждений во всем проекте.

Comment: @aepot, не лучший способ сделать кодовую базу поддерживаемой в дальнейшем

Comment: Сделайте реальный компилирующийся пример. Текущий пример не компилируется. Если добавить модификаторы public, то никаких предупреждений не выдаётся. Так-то суть вопроса понятна, но без живого примера нет смысла вести дальнейшее обсуждение.

Comment: Не должно быть методов типа `Initialize()`. Создание объекта должно полностью совершаться в конструкторе. Точка. / Тут напрашивается фабрика. А ещё лучше, правильное делегирование обязанностей зависимостям.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov насчёт грязной архитектуры не могу не согласиться. Увы, ресурсов на исправление легаси кода взять не от куда, поэтому шёл по пути наименьшего сопротивления, что бы довериться возможностям статического анализатора. Спасибо за совет.

Comment: [null-forgiving](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving) - `InnerObj.Property!.ToString()` - вручную можно заткнуть анализатор. Выше в комментариях уже есть пример, но без ссылки.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov p.s. модель и вправду отражает всю суть вопроса, живой пример отличается лишь большим количеством свойств, методов и вместо int? коллекция объектов.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, да, остаётся лишь только запрещать null вручную, там где это необходимо, благодарствую. (Ну или смотреть в сторону анализаторов от resharper)